# Why is print not showing the whole line?

Tags: python, string, printing, encode

Why when I'm printing the request.decode("utf-8") the first of the line isn't printed, I tried a lot of things and concluded that whenever there is some text before it and in the exact same line, it will be ignored. (adding a print with end='' is ignored too)

SYN is what I receive from the TCP client.
The output is in the end.

```
import threading

IP = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 9998

def main():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((IP, PORT))

    server.listen(5)
    print(f'[*] Listening on {IP} : {PORT}')

    while True:

        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f'[*] Accepted connection from {address[0]}:{address[1]}')
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
        client_handler.start()

def handle_client(socket):
    with socket as sock:
        request = sock.recv(1024)
        print(f'[*] Received: {request.decode("utf-8")}')
        sock.send(b'AKNOWLEDGEMENT')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
[*] Listening on 0.0.0.0 : 9998
[*] Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:22703
SYN
```

Comment: You should print out your response in hex. My guess is that there is a CR in there which overwrites ‘Received’.

Comment: Please post your client code.

Comment: Change `print(f'[*] Received: {request.decode("utf-8")}')` to `print(f'[*] Received: {request}')` to dump the received data as-is.